# Selection property not working

Tags: c#, winforms, selection

```
string holder = richTextBox1.Selection.Text;
```

The `.Selection` produces an error :

> 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selection' and no extension method 'Selection' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: show more code, what is richTextBox1 ?

Comment: richTextBox1 is where I will enter the values that I want. sort of like a textPane in java. Then I want to get the data from that richTextBox1 and place it in an array list or in this case in a string variable but it generates an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RichtTextBox` doesn't have a `Selection` property, hence the error message.

It does have a [`SelectionStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SelectionLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which you can use to get the selection text yourself:

```
string selectedText = rtb.Text.Substring(rtb.SelectionStart, rtb.Length);
```

Or simply use [`SelectedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string selectedText = rtb.SelectedText;
```

Comment: .SelectedText also generates an error: "string does now contain definition for 'SelectedText'.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Typo