# RichTextBox.Selection property not detected by Visual Studio. Missing using reference?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I want to use the selection property from my `RichTextBox`. I added a reference to `PresentationFramework.dll` on my project and a using reference to namespace System.Windows.Controls on my code. According to Microsoft documentation, that should work ([RichTextBox.Selection Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selection?view=netframework-4.8))

However, Visual Studio fails to find myRichTextBox.Selection and gives me an error. Am I missing some reference or something?

The code throwing the error is this: it's a function that receives a RTF text and loads it into RichTextBox with rich format

```
 private void LoadRTF(string RTFtext)
 {
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(RTFtext));
     myRichTextBox.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
 } //LoadRTF
```

But the thing here is that Visual Studio doesn't recognize Selection property. Even a simple line like

```
 TextSelection ts = myRichTextBox.Selection;
```

throws the same error

Comment: if the new changes need to clean and build the project. maybe it can fix it. and what is your error exactly ?

Comment: Already tried to clean and build Project. Error i I got it in spanish, it says something like "System.Windows.RichTextBox doesn't contain a definition for "Selection" and none extension method "Selection" that takes one argument of type System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox has been found (missing using directive or assembly reference?)"

Comment: myRichTextBox is a RichTextBox control in a Windows Forms. I'll update now question with the code I'm using.

Comment: see this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521100/4118900

Comment: Well, according to Microsoft, RichTextBox is supposed to have a selection property. And I need that property to use the Load method that will get RTF from MemoryStream.

Comment: do you have error in compile time or run time ?

Comment: Compile time, the one I more or less translated from spanish:  "System.Windows.RichTextBox doesn't contain a definition for "Selection" and none extension method "Selection" that takes one argument of type System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox has been found (missing using directive or assembly reference?)"

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/601869/4118900

Comment: You need to be clear which RTB you are using: The one from WinForms or the WPF one !! They are NOT THE SAME !! -  If your project is Winfroms most likely there is no need to use the WPF one!?

Comment: Ok, I was using the one from Windows.Forms and I need the one from Windows.Controls. Do you know how I could add a RichTextBox from Windows.Controls in my Windows Forms, or how to assign Windows.Forms.RichTextBox to a Windows.Controls.RichTextBox?

Comment: _I need the one from Windows.Controls_ Why??

Comment: I wanted to use the Load method from the Windows.Controls control. Now I can try to use the LoadFile method from the Windows.Forms control, so no need to use the Wdinwos.Controls.RichTextBox anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the Windows Forms RichTextBox control, Selection property is not available. You can use either the [SelectedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext?view=netframework-4.8) or the [SelectedRtf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedrtf?view=netframework-4.8) property to get the current selection content.

As for the part where you want to load content from a MemoryStream to the control, you can use the `LoadFile(Stream, RichTextBoxStreamType)` overload of the [LoadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile?view=netframework-4.8) method, like this:

```
private void LoadRTF(string RTFtext)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(RTFtext));
    myRichTextBox.LoadFile(stream, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
```

Lastly, if you really want to use the WPF RichTextBox control in a Winforms application, you can do it by using the ElementHost control, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Tried that code, but it's throwing error when reading saved RTF. More precisely, the string "tf1ansiansicpg1252deff0deflang3082{onttbl{0nilcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
viewkind4uc1pard0s17 Este texto esta en negrita0par" is not recognized as rich text by LoadFile

Comment: Actually, I think I'm gonna post a new question asking about this piece of code. After all, the problem of this question is solved.